# Efficient algorithm to sort a sequence using few transpositions?

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

I am interested in restricted sorting problem:

If we restrict sorting algorithms to use transpositions (swapping integers in two non-adjacent positions) and restrict the number of transpositions then some sequences are sortable and others are not.

Note that sequence $A$ may contain some **repeated** integers

Formally, the problem is:

**Input**: a sequence $A=[a_1, a_2, ..., a_{2N}]$ of $2N$ positive (possibly repeated) integers.

**Question**: Is it possible to sort sequence $A$ using $N$ transpositions of non-adjacent positions?

> Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to solve this problem? Or Is it NP-complete?

This was posted on [CS Theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27858/efficient-recognition-of-sequences-sortable-by-transpositions) long time ago without getting an answer.

Comment: The question is presented badly -- the fact you are restricting to the special case of disallowing the transposition of adjacent elements is probably the most important aspect of the question to emphasize, but there isn't the slightest hint of this in the main exposition; instead it is relegated to an addendum that masquerades as being a mere clarification.

Comment: Also, you forgot to mention you had also cross posted to mathoverflow.

Comment: @Hurkyl I fixed it.